# Percentage based on Profit and Loss

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What was the Percentage of Discount given?
>
> 1. 23.5 % profit was earned by selling an almirah for rs 12,350.
> 2. If there were no Discount,the earned profit would have been 30%
> 3. The cost price of the almirah was rs 10,000
>
> for these Question option are
>
> - only I and II
> - only II and III
> - only I and III
> - Any two of the three
> - None of these
>
> options are used to find the discount with the help of three
>   statements , or only two statements like that

I have tried:

**From first statement:**

```
Profit will be 23.5 percent

Selling Price will be 12,350

Cost Price =?

12350*100/123.5 = C.P

10,000 = C.P
```

**From second statement**

```
when no discount offered

Profit = 30 %

therefore selling price =130/100 * 10,000

S.P = 13,000

Difference in selling Price = 13,000 - 12,350 = 650

Percentage discount = 650/12350 *100 = 5.26%
```

I got the answer option  a that is from one and second statement we can answer this question

**But the answer is given as  last option None of these what i am doing Mistake?Please anyone guide me**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In question first statement you found cost price. But you are not able to find marked price. As for offered discount you need to know marked price.

Now placing things in an order -

From statement I -

After discount original SP 12350.

We can also calculate CP from it. CP = 10000.

From statement II -

MP = 13000 (Also SP if no discount).

Thus, I and II give the answer.

II and III can not give the answer. Because we require profit percentage with discount and profit percentage without discount. So II and III are not sufficient.

Since III gives C.P. = Rs. 10,000, I and III give the answer.

Therefore, I and II [or] I and III give the answer.

So option 5th is answer.

Comment: I am not able to understand @Amar, why we need Marked price,what is the use of Marked price, could you please explain ellaborately

Comment: You went showroom to buy shirt. There's 25% discount . On which amount you calculate discount?

Comment: based on Cost Price only they are giving discount @Amar

Comment: Nope. First thing you do you check tag for price. On tag there is Marked price. Not cost price. Cost price is price at which shopkeeper purchase it.

Comment: ok yes tagged price @Amar

Comment: From these problem how MP = 13000 (Also SP if no discount).you are telling Marked price?

Comment: Let me explain you in detail. Suppose you are shopkeeper. You purchase one shirt for 100 rupees. And you want to earn profit of 50 rupees. So it means you have to sell it for 150 rupees. But you know your customer ask for some discount. Then you write the price 200 rupees. And set discount so that you get 150 rupees on selling.

Comment: But original SP is 12350 after some discount. If he sell on no discount then it's 13000.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55265/discussion-between-amar-and-learning-user).

Comment: from first statement itself we can find cost price, then what is the use of third statement @Amar

Comment: what is the use of third statement @Amar,From I and II is enough for the problem

Comment: Sorry for skipping that.  Now check my answer.

Comment: how  1 and 3 gives the answer? @Amar

Comment: from first itself we can get the Cost price @Amar